# Wordpress enqueue error, How to fix?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I keep getting this error in wordpress from the php when I try to test-run this code, which is identical to the tutorial.

***Notice: Use of undefined constant add - assumed 'add' in /home/genera58/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteenG-CHILD/functions.php on line 6***

***Fatal error: Call to undefined function action() in /home/genera58/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteenG-CHILD/functions.php on line 6
string(11) "HALO Fatal:" string(35) "Call to undefined function action()" string(79) "/home/genera58/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteenG-CHILD/functions.php" int(6)***

CODE:

```
<?php 

function twentyfifteen_child_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'transition js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/transition.js' );
}
add-action('wp_enqueue_scripts','twentyfifteen_child_scripts');
```

What is it asking me to fix exactly? everything has the right quotations.
sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: we'll did you try add_action(), hyphens are not allowed as function names in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function you are looking for `add_action()` and not `add-action()`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Also note that the hyphen is not allowed as part of a function name, there are ways to use it that way, but that is far outside the scope of this issue.